# Azure DevOps Team Retrospectives - Reset Vote Count

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, sprint, vote-up-buttons

We have a number of Team Retrospective votes which were incremented accidentally, when some users repeatedly clicked the upvote button in error. We're now seeking ways to reset the vote count for all affected Retrospectives. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current Retrospectives does not support this operation.

I suggest you put your suggestions in their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-retrospectives/issues), maybe they can follow your suggestions to add new features.